# Autofit columns CSV file vba

Tags: csv, ms-access, vba

I have code that exports Access tables to .csv. However, I am not trying to autofit the columns after export. I am getting a "Object variable or With block variable not set".

Also is it possible to open mulptiple csv files and autofit within the same procedure?

Below is the code, I appreciate any assistance you can give.

```
Function AutoFits()

Dim ObjFSO As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

 Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
       ObjFSO.Opentextfile "C:\filename.csv"
       With ObjFSO

        ws("sheet1").Select

             .Columns("A:O").Select
             .Selection.Columns.AutoFit
             .activeworkbook.Save

       End With

       ObjFSO.Quit
       Set ObjFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Your With statement is referring to the scripting object and you are trying to set sheet based properties on this object. Hence the error

Answer (score 0):

This below should work. Please note you are unable to retain any formatting (including column widths) if you save back as a CSV so you need to save a xls file.

```
Sub AutoFits()

   Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\filename.csv"

    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:O").Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\filename.xls"

End Sub
```

and to loop through all csv files in a directory ...

```
Function AutoFitsAllFiles()
    Dim file As String

    file = Dir("c:\*.csv")

   While (file <> "")
     Application.Workbooks.Open "c:\" & file

    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:O").Select

    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\" & Left(file, Len(file) - 3) & "xls"

    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

    file = Dir
  Wend


End Function
```